# Passing by reference using CreateThread()

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, pass-by-reference

I know the general gist of how to launch a thread using CreateThread() in C++, and have created an application that successfully launches them. I know that if I were to use C11 threads pass by reference isn't a problem, but I am wondering how/if this is possible using CreateThread(), or any earlier (non C-11) threading mechanisms.

Comment: Some sort of code snippit to demonstrate the lines you were thinking along or the things you have tried would help here. You can't pass anything by reference to CreateThread because its fingerprint doesn't take any references. Are you talking about *capture by reference* in the lambda you might provide to a std::thread constructor?

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't necessarily looking for a complete solution within my application, was just wondering if such a thing was possible using CreateThread(). Turns out my application worked by passing a variable by reference through a function that was wrapping the thread call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look, you can certainly find some C++ thread APIs that are older than those in C++11 (e.g., MFC and Qt both support threading). If memory serves, they use references in places, but unless you're using them for the rest of your application, you probably don't care much about them.

The "raw" APIs (POSIX, Win32, etc.) are generally based strictly on C. They don't use of include anything (including references) that isn't found in C.